# Can I use BlueMix Twilio from an on premise application, without an additional bluemix server/service?

Tags: sms, twilio, ibm-cloud

can I use Twilio (just to send SMS) from an on premise application, without the use of additional bluemix services? I would like to have Twilio as a "starter" on bluemix, and eventually move other services to bluemix at a later point in time,...
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio is an external Software-as-a-Service vendor. It's not tied to the IBM Bluemix platform. You can use Twilio from anywhere provided you can send REST API requests.

Comment: Understood. Thought I can use Twilio stand alone on BlueMix and move other services to BlueMix later. But seems to go directly with Twilio is the only way.